# "dimension types not allowed" when I put float in dimen

Tags: android

I added this line to my values/dimen.xml

```
<item format="float" name="list_divider_thickness" type="dimen">0.66dp</item>
```

and I get

```
Error:(1015, 69) Dimension types not allowed (at 'list_divider_thickness' with value '0.66dp').
```

(I want a divider that appears as 2 pixels on xxhdpi , and 1 pixel on low/med density devices, that's why I'm using 0.66)

Answer (score 0):

for adding floats, we dont need to use the syntax in the original question, I changed it to

```
<dimen name="list_divider_thickness">0.66dp</dimen>
```

and it worked fine.

It was android studio which automatically generated the entry the wrong way when I pressed alt+enter and selected extract dimension resource.